# Delphi XE2 DLL crashes when called from Web API running on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, pinvoke, azure-web-app-service

My C# Web API project is calling a native Delphi DLL using p/invoke.

Everything works fine on my Windows 10 development machine until I publish the project to an Azure App Service web app.

When the DLL is invoked from the App Service and tries to create a hidden form an Access Violation occurs and the website crashes.
In the example below the test form is an empty Delphi VCL form.

```
// Delphi XE2 DLL:
function TestFunc: Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Result := OpenTestForm(nil);
end;

function OpenTestForm(aOwner: TComponent): Boolean;
begin
  frmTest := TfrmTest.Create(aOwner); // Access Violation here !!!
  try
    Result := True;
  finally
    frmTest.Free;
  end;
end;

// C# 
[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool TestFunc();
```

C# Web API Project: .NET Core RC1 (1.0.0-rc1-final) using .NET Framework 4.5.1

Delphi XE2: 32 bit DLL

Works fine on Windows 10 (dev machine) and on Windows Server 2012 R2 (Azure VM).
Azure App Service is running as a 32 bit process.

Comment: A lot of servers dont allow forms to be created from services.

Comment: Do some debugging. Find out what the access violation is, which line of code generates it, which memory access is invalid. If I had to guess, I'd wonder if the process was running as a service that did not allow interaction with desktop. Ask yourself why you feel the need to create a VCL form? That part of your design is clearly wrong.

Comment: The DLL generates reports using Digital Metaphors Report Builder. In order to use Report Builder we have to place it in a VCL form.

Comment: That appears to be your mistake, designing your program in such a way that it needs to create UI objects in an environment that does not support doing so.

Comment: I agree with David that this is a poor design. This is a temporary solution for an early release and we will rewrite the reports in the future using a simpler and cleaner approach that doesn't involve a native DLL. In the meantime I'm kind of forced to deploy the Web API on a dedicated VM since it doesn't crash there.